# android-How to repeat a lineaLayou several times without using listView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

What I mean is this , you know we've custom listView that we can make several rows with every thing we want in . 
i want to do the same but I don't want to use listView . I want to make 10 rows that contain some text . something like this :

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/layoutround"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dama"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_weather" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/maxt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_weatherother" />

   </LinearLayout>
```

I want to repeat this layout in my java file ,How is that possible ? 
The reason I don't want to use listView is because I have an image as my background , If I use listView I can't use this background .

How can I do that ?

thanks

Comment: ... can't you make your ListView **see trough** (in other words, **transparent**)?!

Comment: The simple answer is "don't". You can have a transparent background for your list items and disable the separators if they bother you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might inflate this xml file, edit the contents accordingly and then append it to a parent ViewGroup. Another idea would be creating a compound ViewGroup which encapsulates your element.
Also, you probably can actually insert a background on a listview (which would be even better).

parent.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
  ...
  android:id="@+id/parentLayout />
```

sibling.xml <- your example

view.java

```
 public View onCreateView(...) {
  ViewGroup root = findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
  LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
  for ( MyData data : dataList ) {
    ViewGroup sibling = (ViewGroup) inflater
      .inflate(R.layout.sibling,null);
    EditText dama = (EditText)sibling.findViewById(R.id.dama);
    dama.setText(data.getTheText());
    root.addView(sibling);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Der Golem said, you could make your `ListView` transparent.
Or, to answer your question, you need to have a root XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/layoutround"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

and in your `Fragment` or `Activity`, you need to
- get a reference to this layout
- inflate the layouts you want to display in the root XML
- or, manually create `Views` like `TextView` etc
- then use `container.addView(myView)`